# Qt phonon module play 5.1 dolby

Tags: c++, qt4, phonon

Is it possible to make qt phonon module play sounds in 5.1 and how it can be done?
By default it plays only in 2.1 I think.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using and what operating systems do you want to deploy your application to? It may require a modification of the Phonon backend to get 5.1 support.

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.0 on Windows.